# iOS Collection View End Detection and refreshing

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a collection view with image views inside, and every time when I come to the last cell I need to call the function to put more images in array with names of images. so how can I detect exactly last cell or the actual end of collection view?

Then after the photos added is the collection view will refreshes by it self or I need to refresh it programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this. You can use your `UICollectionViewDelegate` and implement

```
- collectionView:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:
```

You use that to check if the index path is for your last cell and if it is, modify your array and then call `reloadData` (yes, you have to do it yourself).